# arithmetic in tex when the data type is not an integer

Tags: calculations, fp

Use case.

I am drafting a contract where I would specify in the beginning an hourly rate using

```
\newcommand{\monthlyrate}{\$10000}
```

And in the following command, I would like to specify a penalty that should be a multiple of the monthlyrate. For example, something like

```
penalty should be 4*\monthlyrate \$
```

Is it possible to let tex do the calculation directly? Of course, I see one of the potential stumbling block would be the \montlyrate is defined as as string, so is not accesible to arithmatic manipulation.

P.S.
Yes, it is not a big deal if I just have to write out in words what I mean. I just feel this has potnetial usage beyond the current use case.

Comment: it would be easier if your `\monthlyrate` was just the value and you used it as `\monthlyrate\$` otherwise you have to remove the `\$` before multiplying which isn't that hard but perhaps makes it unnecessarily complicated

Comment: The problem with this approach would be that the monetary unit is something that I also would like to set as a variable in the beginning of my document. So it could be US dollar, or British Pound, or Chinese Yuan.

Comment: but in your snippet above you are printing the unit explicitly, you are not using a variable. Better think first about a better input and data model. You could e.g. use a key-val system `monthlyrate=1000,monthlyrate-currency=\$` which stores the values and then write some commands to extract and use them im various ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\monthlyrate[1][1]{\$\the\numexpr#1*1000\relax}
\begin{document}

   The monthly rate is \monthlyrate\ equivalently \monthlyrate[12] per year.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you give LuaTeX a chance? When it comes to divisions, then you will see TeX' limits.

```
\directlua{M=2000}

The monthly rate is \$\directlua{tex.print(M)} equivalently 
\$\directlua{tex.print(M*12)} per year.

\bye
```

Edit: `\$` added (see comment).

Comment: but this is omitting the main part of the question which is stepping round the `\$` (also latex, even with pdftex, has IEEE decimal arithmetic implemented so division isn't really an issue if that is needed)

Comment: You are right, I added `\$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\monthlyrate{\$750}
\newcommand\Penalty[1]{\$\the\numexpr#1
  *\expandafter\stripdollar\monthlyrate\relax}
\def\stripdollar#1#2\relax{#2\relax}
\begin{document}

The monthly rate is \monthlyrate.

The penalty should be \Penalty{4}
\end{document}
```

[image]